# error after installing node & npm on a macbook air 2018

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

after downloading the installer and following the installation steps from here https://nodejs.org/en/download

I get the following error when I try `node -v`:

`dyld[2548]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib Referenced from: <7B868858-AA8F-3A42-B7B8-7516EF3E5617> /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.24.1/bin/node Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.68.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache) Abort trap: 6`

I tried reinstalling node.js, restarting after install to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself some time/trouble and install HomeBrew. Afterwards you can simply run `brew install node`.

Or, if you still want to install Node manually after installing HomeBrew, you can try manually re-installing the missing library. `brew install icu4c`